# What should be the Schema for Donation table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema

I am creating a web portal for an organization and I am a bit confused on this part.

They will be receiving donations from their registered members as well as guests. I was thinking of creating a users table that is solely used for registered members and no guests etc. because users table will contain unique "email" column and I don't want it to be null.

For donations, I can add user_id foreign key for users table.

What I am thinking of doing is that I should add "name" and "mobile" columns in donations table, so that if it's a guest, we should only get his name and phone number and put in donations table. Do you think this is the right way?

For just demo purpose I am showing you the table:

users table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_mobile_unique` (`mobile`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

donations table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `donations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve data problems - some better than others.  I would not have a separate user table if you are already getting some details.  Rather have a REGISTERED_USER column or along those lines to denote a "full user" versus a partial.  Then everything stays relatively simple AND the user has an option to become a full user later, which I assume you want for donations... :)

Comment: Thanks @Anthony the thing I had in my mind was that if there are many guests, wouldn't it be slow for members to login/update their profiles? As, when the user logs in, the whole table will be searched for?

Comment: You can always just ran a periodic maintenance script to remove old inactive users.  We have tables with over 200 million rows in production.  If you get to that number of users, you probably have other problems, like too much money :)  Your table is relatively small and with the right indexes, you should not have any problems with performance.

Comment: 200 million is a big number. I doubt if they will hit this much in next 2 years. And we can certainly use the partitions for that purpose. I guess I will go with your approach. Thanks